# XSLT how to partition a sequence into sub-sequences

Tags: xslt, grouping, partitioning

I have an XML file that contains a sequence of strings

```
<ModsConfigData>
  <buildNumber>1393</buildNumber>
  <activeMods>
    <li>Core</li>
    <li>ZhentarFix</li>
    <li>WorldPawnGC</li>
    <li>HugsLib</li>
    <!-- more entries -->
  </activeMods>
</ModsConfigData>
```

And I wish to partition the long list of elements into subsets of a given length -- in my case, lengths of five. The purpose is to then work with the subsets to generate a table structure that is five across and however many rows it takes to consume the full list.

The output I'm wanting to achieve is a subset of BBCode like so:

```
[table]
  [tr]
    [td]Core[/td][td]ZhentarFix[/td][td]WorldPawnGC[/td] ...
  [/tr]
  [tr]
    [td] ... (next set of five entries) [/td]
  [/tr]
[/table]
```

It looks like a set of queries to me. There are probably ways to do a for-each loop, and position() mod 5 or position div 5 might be a way to get there. I'm not familiar enough with the grouping instruction to even guess if can be of assistance.

This is what I'm currently using, any improvements welcome.

```
    <xsl:variable name="modsConfigFile" select="document('ModsConfig.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="5"/>

    <xsl:template match="/ModsConfigData/activeMods">
        <xsl:text>[hr][table]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of>           
            <xsl:apply-templates
                select="li[position() mod $groupSize = 1]"/>
        </xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:text>[/table]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>  

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <xsl:text>[tr]</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select= 
                ".|following-sibling::li[position() &lt; $groupSize]"/>
        <xsl:text>[/tr]</xsl:text>
        <br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li" >
        <xsl:text>[td]</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>[/td]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42655038/3016153 ?

Answer (score 2):

> This is what I'm currently using,

You can't be "using" that, because it doesn't work. It doesn't work because (among other things):

1. you cannot place `xsl:apply-templates` within `xsl-value-of`; and
2. you have two templates matching `li`, with no distinction between them.

To do it the way you have started, you need to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:variable name="groupSize" select="5"/>

<xsl:template match="/ModsConfigData">
    <xsl:text>[table]&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="activeMods/li[position() mod $groupSize = 1]"/>
    <xsl:text>[/table]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:text>  [tr]&#10;    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select= ". | following-sibling::li[position() &lt; $groupSize]" mode="cell"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;  [/tr]&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li" mode="cell">
    <xsl:text>[td]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>[/td]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above is applied to the following test input:

**XML**

```
<ModsConfigData>
    <buildNumber>1393</buildNumber>
    <activeMods>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>E</li>
        <li>F</li>
        <li>G</li>
        <li>H</li>
        <li>I</li>
        <li>J</li>
        <li>K</li>
        <li>L</li>
    </activeMods>
</ModsConfigData>
```

the **result** will be:

```
[table]
  [tr]
    [td]A[/td][td]B[/td][td]C[/td][td]D[/td][td]E[/td]
  [/tr]
  [tr]
    [td]F[/td][td]G[/td][td]H[/td][td]I[/td][td]J[/td]
  [/tr]
  [tr]
    [td]K[/td][td]L[/td]
  [/tr]
[/table]
```